# How to Make Exception Handling on VBA Excel Form Combobox?

Tags: vba, excel, exception, combobox, userform

I have this userform that i'm developing for my report formatting task. My whole code is finished, there are only 2 problems that i need to work on.

1. Making my VBA application work on every excel file that user choose
2. Exception Handling for ComboBoxes on my form.

(***Edit: I hope trying to get attention of people who are interested in this question to another stackoverflow.com topic is not against forum rules***)

You guys can reach first problem's topic from here: (There is already one suggestion but i'm little bit confused. So it would be super for alternative suggestions) http://bit.ly/VnF3cK

And about my second problem, when i click empty place of combobox, i can type whatever i want, but i want to restrict it, so users can only choose values [1-5] that i put inside of combobox. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your secondary question, you need to change the ComboBox's `Style` property to `frmStyleDropDownList`

Comment: any suggestion for primary question?

Comment: Make a new question regarding ONLY your first question and also explain it in a bit more detail :)

Comment: Hi Francis, Thanks for reply. I already shared my primary question but i think it didn't get enough attention and i thought it might be beneficial to shere the link in this topic as long as it is not against forum rule :) http://bit.ly/VnF3cK